# Select rows added after a particular row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, `users`:

```
user    name    date
----    ----    ----
```

I want to select the users that create an account after user X.
I cannot select by date, because some users create their accounts at the same time.

ex:

```
marie - Marie C - 2015-11-02 00:24:01
josh - Josh B - 2015-11-02 00:24:01
joe - Joe D - 2015-11-02 00:24:01
anna - Anna B - 2015-11-02 00:24:01
```

I want to select all users that come after `josh` (i.e., `joe` and `anna`). Can I do this?

something like: `select user after 'josh' from users...`

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  If you want to understand sequences, then include an auto_increment column in your table.  Normally, a creation date is sufficient, but you seem to have things happening at the same time.

Comment: Do you have ids in user table? Cause if so, then you can do `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id > [some_id]`

Comment: If there is an autoincrement user id, it's possible to query greater than that but it may not be fool proof. Otherwise, this can't be done as there's no criteria for 'joe' and 'anna' other than that they've appeared after visually. An SQL query can't detect that.

Comment: The [documentation on the `SELECT` statement is very complete](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) so if you're ever curious what it can do, start there.